# Google cloud platform and firebase push notification pricing and limitations

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-platform

I am using Firebase to send push notifications to Android and iOS devices, however I am not sure about the pricing at all.

I am using the Spark plan:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?authuser=0

And they tell there that Push notification services are enabled. They doesn't talk about any limit of notifications I can send. This is make me concern. Is this unlimited notification means I can send 5 billion notification a minute? What's the deal in here.

I wanted to use Google Maps, but their pricing was just like a mafia - you don't understand just anything - they oblige you to put your credit card AND they **don't let you remove your credit card!!!**

So I decided to put back all of what I have with those mafia services.

If someone can please explicit this kind of business logic it will be just great.

My question:

1. How many push notification can I send, is it limit to some kind of total pushes a month, day, week or a second (moment)? - using Firebase.
2. Should I use Google Cloud Platform for using the Firebase - only for Push services? Or I can delete the Google Cloud Platform account and disable it at all.

Comment: There are no limits or cost.  A GCP project is the same thing as a Firebase project.

Comment: I don't know why you closed the question. Did they answer there this question: In order to use Firebase push services - should I have Google Cloud Platform account?

Comment: Since a Firebase project is a GCP project, then yes, you need a GCP account (which is also a Firebase account).  They are the same.  Firebase just activates APIs in a GCP project.

Comment: And should I add my credit card to the GCP?  OR use an api key from GCP in order to make the push services working?

Comment: There's no credit card required to get FCM to work.  If you have questions about billing in general, please contact Firebase support, since Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/